# Need a custom richedit control (Open-Source)

Tags: c++, windows, fonts, open-source, richedit

I need a custom Rich-Edit control for making a text processing application. It must be Open-Source so that I can add my own feature. The windows default Rich-Edit controls are buggy for me cause I'm using my own font ( Bangla Font ). I've used all version of windows Rich-Edit but none those works well for me.

So now I need an owner drawn Rich-Edit control which must be Open-Source and also should include all the features of windows rich edit control.
I've searched on Google but have not found any useful.

If anybody know, Please give me the website link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/)

It's Open Source and Notepad++ uses it.

EDIT: since Scintilla isn't really made for that kind of rich edit you could download [Open Office's source code](http://openoffice.apache.org/source.html) and find out how they do it.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Actually I've already tried Scintilla but it has made especially for editing programming source-codes. I forgot to mention in my question that I need the rich edit control for making a text processing application and Scintilla has not all the features of windows rich edit control.

Comment: Thanks again for informing me about the Open Office's source code. I will check this out and hope this will help.